# get the number of elements inside an array returned by mongoose on a find() callback containing an ObjectId

Tags: mongoose

I would like to count the number of elements inside an array.

The problem is `.length` doesn't work in this specific case using the mongoose `find()` method:

I read on the documentation this `find()` method return an array (i only select the field `_id` on my `find()` call).

The array returned is exactly syntaxed: `[{ _id: 51153212835b351826000001 }]`

The `.length` method apply on it return `undefined`. I made some tests with node and it doesn't work either since there is no `quotes` to encapsule the value of `_id`.

The type of this value is `ObjectId` which is provided by `mongoose`. And i can access it this way `Doc.id` without any trouble.

The thing is, this is the format returned by the `find()` method of mongoose, is there a way to get the number of elements found on the callback ?

I didn't find it on the documentation, the callback looks like `function(err, Doc)` but mongoose does provide this value on the update callback `function(error, numAffected)`
so i am wondering maybe we can also access it with `find()`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for your `find` call?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you show here is not a valid array literal. To be more exact, the only element in this array is an object and it is this object that is not a valid object literal because the value of `_id` is not a number. Not the `b` within the value. Therefore not just the `length` property will not work but this string cannot be evaluated to a valid JS object. The value of `_id` needs to be quoted.

Comment: `var a  = [{ '_id': '51153212835b351826000001' }]` works just fine.

Comment: Yes that's the observation i made, and as i said, this is the result returned by the `find()` method of mongoose, so i can't change it unless parsing it...

Comment: This is very strange then. I don't know mongoose but it definitely shouldn't return an invalid literal.

Comment: Is the field type for the `_id` defined as string?

Comment: The 51153212835b351826000001 value is an `ObjectId` (type provided by mongoose).

Answer (score 0):

I finally use the `count` mongoose method because of this.